# No servlet response via Ajax

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, servlets, websphere

I've written a simple servlet for processing an Ajax request. On the server side, the `doPost` is called, but the data that I've set in the response object is not reflected on the client. (Actually, I'm not getting anything on the client according to Firebug). I'm using jQuery to handle the Ajax.

Client code:

```
$.post(
   '/mapped/url?param=' + $('#eleId').val(),
      function(data){
        alert(data);
      },
      "xml"
);
```

On the server:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("!!!In post!!!!");
    // some calculations go here

    response.setContentType("application/xml");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

    response.getWriter().write("<data><param number=\"\"></param></data>");
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Read the server logs and remove any `<filter>` from `web.xml` to exclude one and other. Note that setting the response status is not possible when the response body is already committed. You should do it beforehand, but still then, setting a status 200 is already by default done. Just remove that line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to debug this in steps as this issue could mean anything from improper Servlet configuration to a bug in the client side code.

1. What status code are you seeing in firebug for the XHR (AJAX) request? (anything other than 200 is a red flag. check server logs)
2. Is your system.out statement getting executed? i.e. is "!!!In post!!!!" logged?
3. Create a simple html with a form that posts to the servlet and see if you get any results back.
4. Depending on the results for above steps, debug further if required.

Comment: 1. I am getting a 200
2. The system.out is getting printed
3. Firebug says I'm getting an empty response, but the xml tab says: XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{7209b27a-18e0-4494-966b-e8951482d9a8} Line Number 1, Column 1:

Comment: Try setting content type to "text/xml"

Answer (score -1):

You may have to explicitly close the output stream -

```
  PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();

  out.println( "Sample response" );
  out.close();
```

Comment: -1: That's already done by the container. If it didn't it would have been a bug in the container and many more people than only the OP would have major trouble.